# Threadsafe dictionary that does lookups with minimal locking

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible to implement a threadsafe dictionary with minimal use of locks if the only methods I want are tryget and insert? Entries will never be deleted and value for a key will always stay the same.

Comment: yes, but how are you going to write into it?

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: AFAIK it internally uses locks

Comment: The [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/#fine-grained-locking-and-lock-free-mechanisms) already employs minimal usage of locks that cause blocking.

Comment: I want no locking for tryget and minimal locking for the rest.Does concurrentdictionary lock on reads?

Comment: How often are you reading (how many times a second)? How often are you writing? How many entries in the dictionary?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,499 may be helpful.

Comment: It depends on the read/write ratio if a different strategy will compete better than the one with the locks

Comment: "no|minimal locking" is not a real performance requirement. The cost of locking heavily depends on usage patterns, etc.

Comment: Use existing `ConcurrentDictionary` unless you have profiled your application and it cause performance problems that you are able to solve yourself... which imply you have a deep understanding of multithreading synchronisation in which case you would not have to ask the question...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx). It contains [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which probably does [what you're after](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/#fine-grained-locking-and-lock-free-mechanisms).